# How to know what values get updated from the UI side in Generic list in C#

Tags: c#, list, silverlight

**Case scenario:**
I have an application in silverlight, in that application we have list which is bind with respective ViewModel in that ViewModel I have three (ID, Name and Age) properties and one of the (Age) property value will be update by the user, from the view or UI. UI displayed a list of records in each list item have NAME is read only and AGE is Editable. (AGE have Textbox in the list Item and it has TwoWay binding with the Age property). When user Update AGE value from the UI side I am getting updated values in the bind list itself due to INotifyPropertyChanged.

In this case I wanted to update only those records only which being updated in the list I don't want to send back entire list to server.

```
public class EmpViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public List<EmpModel> Employees { get; set; }
    public ICommand SaveCommand { get; set; }
    private List<EmpModel> _employees;

    public EmpViewModel()
    {
        SaveCommand = new BaseCommand(UpdataInfo, CanUpdataInfo);
        this.Employees = new List<EmpModel>();
        _employees = new List<EmpModel>();
    }

    public void GetEmployeeInfo()
    {
        Employees = new List<EmpModel>
        { 
                new EmpModel { ID =1, NAME="Amar", AGE=0},
                new EmpModel { ID =2, NAME="Sameer", AGE=0},
                new EmpModel { ID =3, NAME="Ram", AGE=0},
                new EmpModel { ID =4, NAME="Rahim", AGE=0}
        };

        _employees = Employees;
    }

    private void UpdataInfo(object param)
    {
        // one way to update information 
        // why --> when user update the from the UI side _employees.AGE value also get update. 
        List<EmpModel> difference = this.Employees.Except(_employees) as List<EmpModel>;
        foreach (var item in difference)
        {
            // save only updated records
        }

        // second way to updat information
        // (?) how to to know what are the values get updated from the UI side in Generic list in C#
    }

    private bool CanUpdataInfo(object param)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void PropertyChangedEvent(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Property Changed EventHandler
    /// </summary>
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class EmpModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public int AGE { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void FirePropertyEvent(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

So here is My Questions for **UpdataInfo()** Method.

> 1) why --> when user update the value from the UI side _employees.AGE
>   value also got update. so i am not able to identify.
>
> 2) (?) how to to know what are the values get updated from the UI side
>   in Generic list in C#.

Please let me know to solve this issue.

Comment: You could use an ObservableCollection<EmpModel> instead of list and add an EventHandler for the CollectionChangedEvent. You can determine the changed item from the eventargs and pass only the changed item to the UpdateInfo() method.

Comment: I have already tried that solution as well however that solution is not feasible in my case. :(

Comment: If the edited item is always selected in a grid or something like that, a dirty solution might be to add a property to your class and bind the selecteditem.

Answer (score -1):

I have seen techniques which include a `IsDirty` property in the model (base) class.

```
public class ModelBase
{
    public bool IsDirty { get; set; }
}

public class EmpModel : ModelBase
{        
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name {get; set;}

    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set
        {
            _age = value;

            // Only if change comes from the user...
            IsDirty = true;
        }
    }
    private int _age;
}
```

When the user changes a value in the UI (e.g. `Age`) you set `IsDirty` to true.

In your `UpdateInfo` method you use only the items which have `IsDirty` == true, perform the update, and then set their `IsDirty` back to false when you are done.